# Problemas com CRUD em C (método de DELETAR)

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, malloc

Na função de deletar, o usuario vai informar um RA que deseja deletar, quando o RA existe na memoria ele deleta, essa parte do codigo funciona...
O problema é quando ele nao encontra na memoria o RA... O sistema trava

```
void deletar(void){
    system("cls");
    //RA que o usuario quer deletar
    int n;
    printf("Digite o RA que deseja deletar: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    do{
        //Esta parte esta ok
        if(p->ra == n){
            //deleta a struct da memoria
            free(p);
            printf("\n\n\nAluno deletado com sucesso\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            //limpando a tela e voltando para o menu principal
            main();
        }

        //Quando ele nao acha o RA o programa trava.
        //unica coisa que falta pra finalizar o metodo
        if (p->anterior==NULL){     
            printf("\n\n\nERRO 404: RA nao existe no sistema\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            //limpando a tela e voltando para o menu principal
            main();
        }

        //vai pra proxima struct
        p = p->anterior;
    }while(1);
}
```

Eu coloquei uma condição pra se o anterior for NULL significa que ele ja percorreu todas as structs, entao nao existe, mas ele nao esta funcionando

Comment: supondo que "deletar" foi chamada pelo "main", então você usa "return" para voltar para main, e não o nome da função main, senão fica uma chamada recursiva

Comment: mas preciso que volte para o menu principal, o programa nao pode fechar depois disso, entendeu?

Comment: funcionou colocando return...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no retorno da função "deletar", onde está "main()" (o que não faz nenhum sentido, pois seria uma chamada recursiva do programa principal) deveria ser "return".

```
void deletar(void)
{
  system("cls");
  //RA que o usuario quer deletar
  int n;
  printf("Digite o RA que deseja deletar: ");
  scanf("%i", &n);

  do {
    //Esta parte esta ok
    if (p->ra == n) {
      //deleta a struct da memoria
      free(p);
      printf("\n\n\nAluno deletado com sucesso\n");
      system("pause");
      system("cls");
      //limpando a tela e voltando para o menu principal
      // main(); // <------------------------- ERROR!!!
      return;
    }

    //Quando ele nao acha o RA o programa trava.
    //unica coisa que falta pra finalizar o metodo
    if (p->anterior==NULL){     
        printf("\n\n\nERRO 404: RA nao existe no sistema\n");
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        //limpando a tela e voltando para o menu principal
        // main(); // <--------------- ERRO!!!
        return;
      }

      //vai pra proxima struct
      p = p->anterior;
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: mas preciso que volte para o menu principal, eu tentei o return e o programa finaliza... Isso nao pode acontecer, entendeu?

Comment: uai, você tem adaptar a lógica da função main para que o programa não termine após a chamada de uma função do crud...provavelmente você vai precisar de um loop, nesse loop você vai ter um menu de opções, com as opções C,R, U, D...e F de fim...enfim, **você** é que tem que definir a lógica do programa

Comment: Ok... entendi, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés da função deletar chamar o main toda vez após a sua execução, segui o conselho do @zentrunix e fiz um loop na função main, assim, quando a função deletar acabar, automaticamente ela já volta pra main.

```
void deletar(void){
    system("cls");
    //RA que o usuario quer deletar
    int n=0;
    printf("Digite o RA que deseja deletar: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    while(p->anterior!=NULL){
        if(p->ra == n){
            //deleta a struct da memoria
            free(p);
            printf("\n\n\nAluno deletado com sucesso\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            //limpando a tela e voltando para o menu principal
            main();
        }

        p = p->anterior;
    }

    //Se nao entrar no if significa que nao foi encontrado o RA
    printf("\n\n\nERRO 404: RA nao existe no sistema\n");
    system("pause");
    //limpando a tela e voltando para o menu principal
    system("cls");
}
```